# Python 3.3 Embedding IDLE/any interpreter into a program

Tags: python, user-interface, embed, interpreter, python-idle

Lets say I want to make a GUI (I prefer tkinter), and I want to put IDLE inside the interface, while having a few other widgets running to the side. How would I do this? I have seen some things like iPython or importing the IDLE lib, but documentation is scarse and I would really like to do this.

I'm making a GUI for a webserver, displaying all sorts of things in realtime like temperature, bandwidth, more things. I would like to be able to show like a small console window that displays everything IDLE display, without having two windows open. Since IDLE prints a lot of data when using the http.server module, I would like to have that in my monitoring GUI.

How would I do this? Does anyone even have experience with something related to this?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Not really what I was looking for, wxpython is python 2.7 right?

Comment: ahh yes ... it certainly is not 3.3 at least ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley that is a bummer. Do you perhaps know of a way to print everything IDLE prints, or display every line that IDLE displays?

Comment: https://github.com/certik/python-3.3/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/PyShell.py this is all I have found ... i didnt look that hard